# modal not showing up

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, jquery-events

The twitter boot strap modal is not triggering up....
I have included the js and CSS...
whats the reason in console it showing up two errors....

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function bootstrap.js:29
>   Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;

Providing my fiddle below

http://jsfiddle.net/rajkumart08/wT5ZR/2/

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            $(function() {
            $('#event-modal').modal({
                backdrop: true;
            });
        });

     </script>



      <div class="container">
      <section>
          <div class="row features">

            <div class="span6">

                 <div id="event-modal" class="modal hide fade">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <a class="close" href="#">x</a>
                        <h3>Modal Heading</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p>Some information</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <a class="btn primary" href="#">Primary</a>
                        <a class="btn secondary" href="#">Secondary</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a href="/events/2-fefewfewfe/rsvps" data-backdrop="true" data-controls-modal="event-modal" data-keyboard="true">click to open model<span class="ico join"></span></a>
```

Answer (score 3):

You should probably listen to what the error says:

```
- $('#event-modal').modal({
-    backdrop: true;
- });

+ $('#event-modal').modal({
+    backdrop: true
+ });
```

EDIT: http://jsfiddle.net/wT5ZR/4/ -- the fiddle was including jQuery *after* bootstrap-modal.  The latter depends on the former.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rajkumart08/wT5ZR/3/ i updated in the fiddle but still not working

Comment: @user2045025 you need to update the fiddle to include jQuery and jQuery UI

Comment: @user2045025 correction, not jQuery UI, but whatever you are adding does not add `$.fn.modal`

Comment: its working here http://jsfiddle.net/rajkumart08/y88WX/24/ but not working in my fiddle

Comment: @user2045025 that's one version back from the one I posted (we're up to version 4 of that fiddle)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rajkumart08/wT5ZR/7/ if i add jquery in external resources why its not working

Comment: @user2045025 external resources are loaded in the order you add them.  jQuery needs to be loaded *first*.

Comment: can i include it by putting script tag since in my project i dont have fiddle option...how to achieve it

Comment: @user2045025 yeah just put the jQuery script tag first